# < Was unexpected at this time...

Tags: batch-file

Alright, so I'm coding a mini batch OS and I'm designing a very dull login screen.
I'm trying to run it, but as soon as I put in my monster of a Username/Password, it won't display it. It'll flash "< Isn't expected at this time". Here's my code below.

```
    @echo off
    title FireyeLauncher
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    :aa
    set /p username=^ Username: 
    set /p password=^ Password: 
        ::Checks to see if USRN and PSW is correct v
        if exist "C:\Fireye\Bin\C\Fireye\System\Users\%username%.bat" (
        call "C:\Fireye\Bin\C\Fireye\System\Users\User_key\%username%.bat"  
        )
            if not exist %username%.bat echo This user doesn't exist!
            goto aa
```

Comment: Does your password have `<` in it? What's in `%username%.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no `<` appears in your batch, then the problem may be with `"C:\Fireye\Bin\C\Fireye\System\Users\User_key\%username%.bat"` (which you haven't shown us) or it may be that you are attempting to use `<` in the username or password (you failed to say what input information you are using)

Certain characters are not allowed in filenames; this may lead to the error you mention.

Comment: Since I've already pre-made an admin file, (The password is monsterous and I don't actually use it) It's here - http://pastebin.com/PdgMyYq3